# SSL Offloading and Open with Explorer

Tags: ssl, open-with-explorer

Recently I came across below article where it states "Open With Explorer" will not work if we are doing SSL Offloading at Load Balancer/Reverse Proxy device level

https://www.vioreliftode.com/index.php/your-client-does-not-support-opening-this-list-with-windows-explorer/

Are there any workarounds or options to have it working with SSL Offloading?

Regards